# How to create a dynamic array with this set of items

Tags: php

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Field1"]=>
    string(8) "80000007"
    ["Field2"]=>
    string(16) "O70000006"
    ["Field3"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Field4"]=>12345
    string(0) ""
   }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Field1"]=>
    string(8) "80000008"
    ["Field2"]=>
    string(16) "O70000007"
    ["Field3"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Field4"]=>78965
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
   array(4) {
    ["Field1"]=>
    string(8) "80000009"
    ["Field2"]=>
    string(16) "H80000006"
    ["Field3"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Field4"]=>12345
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

I have the above array i want to store this items of array into another temp array and use it . Here is what iam doing

```
 $arr_tmp = array();
foreach ($result['record'] as $key => $value){
                $arr_tmp['Field1'] =  $value['Field1'];
                $arr_tmp['Field2'] =  $value['Field2'];
                $arr_tmp['Field3'] =  $value['Field3'];
                $arr_tmp['Field4'] =  $value['Field4'];
}
```

when i do v`ar_dump($arr_tmp)`. Iam getting only the last record in the array. I need the same result set in this $arr_tmp when using foreach loop  so that i can add some more items to this array .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've only created a single arr_tmp array, and overwrite the values on each loop iteration. Possibly you'd want something like:

```
$arr_tmp[] = array('Field1' => $value['Field1'], 'Field2' => $value['Field2'], etc...)
```

inside the loop instead.

But, unless I'm reading your original array wrong, this will simply re-create the original array with new keys, so that begs the question... why? Wouldn't it be easier to just do:

```
$arr_tmp = $original_array;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr_tmp = array();
foreach ($result['record'] as $key => $value){
    $cur = array();
    $cur['Field1'] =  $value['Field1'];
    $cur['Field2'] =  $value['Field2'];
    $cur['Field3'] =  $value['Field3'];
    $cur['Field4'] =  $value['Field4'];
    $arr_tmp[] = $cur;
}
```